# Obtain the value data of a Windows Registry

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

I have been writing a Batch Script in Windows 10, that wants to execute sequentially two R Scripts, one using a 32bit R and another using a 64bit R. In order to do this in any computer I share this batch script with, I need to determine the location of the existing R32bit and R64bit installations in the computer that uses this batch script.

In R identifying the folder paths from the Registry can be done with:

```
# find the path to a R32bit and 64bit R installations 
fp32 <- file.path("SOFTWARE", "R-core", "R32", fsep="\\") 
fp64 <- file.path("SOFTWARE", "R-core", "R64", fsep="\\")

# build the Rscript paths
32bit_Rscript <- paste0(readRegistry(fp32, "HLM")$InstallPath,"\\bin\\i386\\Rscript.exe")
64bit_Rscript <- paste0(readRegistry(fp64, "HLM")$InstallPath,"\\bin\\x64\\Rscript.exe")
```

However, I have not found a way to do this through an Windows Batch Script. I am able to retrieve the key value:

```
 reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\R-core\R32 /v InstallPath
 reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\R-core\R64 /v InstallPath
```

However, this query returns a number of values, including the folder path I want, for example:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core\R64
         InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1
```

**Question:** How can I single out from this registry query only the folder path to assign this to a variable in a batch script?

Comment: The task, or the same techniques for it, have been used on this site, under the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, thousands of times before. Please, in future use the search facility, and adapt the results as needed. The following example should define variables named `InstallPath_32` and `InstallPath_64`. ```@For %%G In (32 64) Do @For /F "EOL=H Tokens=1,2,*" %%H In ('%SystemRoot\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\R-core\R%%G" /V "InstallPath" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "%%H_%%G=%%~J"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` lets you run a command and get its output as lines you can parse.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set v=
for /F "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('2^>nul reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "CurrentVersion"^|find "REG_"') do @set v=%%b
if defined v echo.The value is %v%
```

(The value queried was changed so it works for everyone running this example.)